# AES+HMAC encryption in multiple threads - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, encryption, aes, hmac

I'm developing a little program to encryp/decrypt a binary file using AES-256 and HMAC to check the results.

My code is based on AESCrypt implementation in Java, but I wanted to modify it to allow multiple threads to do the job simultaneously.

I get the size of original bytes and calculate the number of 16 bytes blocks per thread, then I startes the threads with information about the offset to apply for reading and writing (because there is a header for the encrypted file, so the offset_write = offset_read+header_length).

When it finishes the encryption I passed the output content (without the header) trough the HMAC to generate the checksum.

The problem is that some bytes get corrupted in the bytes between two threads.

Code of main:

```
//..
// Initialization and creation of iv, aesKey
//..

in = new FileInputStream(fromPath);
out = new FileOutputStream(toPath);

//..
// Some code for generate the header and write it to out
//..
double totalBytes = new Long(archivo.length()).doubleValue();
int bloquesHilo = new Double(Math.ceil(totalBytes/(AESCrypt.NUM_THREADS*AESCrypt.BLOCK_SIZE))).intValue();
int offset_write = new Long((out.getChannel()).position()).intValue();

for (int i = 0; i < AESCrypt.NUM_THREADS; i++)
{
    int offset = bloquesHilo*AESCrypt.BLOCK_SIZE*i;
    HiloCrypt hilo = new HiloCrypt(fromPath, toPath, ivSpec, aesKey, offset, offsetInicio, bloquesHilo, this);
    hilo.start();
}
```

Code for a thread (class HiloCrypt):
    public class HiloCrypt extends Thread {

```
    private RandomAccessFile in;
    private RandomAccessFile out;

    private Cipher cipher;
    private Mac hmac;
    private IvParameterSpec ivSpec2;
    private SecretKeySpec aesKey2;

    private Integer num_blocks;
    private Integer offset_read;
    private Integer offset_write;

    private AESCrypt parent;

    public HiloCrypt(String input, String output, IvParameterSpec ivSpec, SecretKeySpec aesKey, Integer offset_thread, Integer offset_write, Integer blocks, AESCrypt parent2) 
    {
        try
        {
                        // If i don't use RandomAccessFile there is a problem copying data
            this.in = new RandomAccessFile(input, "r");
            this.out = new RandomAccessFile(output, "rw");

            int total_offset_write = offset_write + offset_thread;

                        // Adjust the offset for reading and writing 
            this.out.seek(total_offset_write);
            this.in.seek(offset_thread);

            this.ivSpec2 = ivSpec;
            this.aesKey2 = aesKey;

            this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AESCrypt.CRYPT_TRANS);
            this.hmac = Mac.getInstance(AESCrypt.HMAC_ALG);

            this.num_blocks = blocks;
            this.offset_read = offset_thread;
            this.offset_write = total_offset_write;
            this.parent = parent2;

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
    }


    public void run()
        {
        int len, last,block_counter,total = 0;
        byte[] text = new byte[AESCrypt.BLOCK_SIZE];

        try{
            // Start encryption objects
            this.cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.aesKey2, this.ivSpec2);
            this.hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(this.aesKey2.getEncoded(), AESCrypt.HMAC_ALG));

            while ((len = this.in.read(text)) > 0 && block_counter < this.num_blocks) 
            {
                this.cipher.update(text, 0, AESCrypt.BLOCK_SIZE, text);
                this.hmac.update(text);

                // Write the block
                this.out.write(text);

                last = len;
                total+=len;

                block_counter++;
            }

            if (len < 0) // If it's the last block, calculate the HMAC
            {
                last &= 0x0f;
                this.out.write(last);

                this.out.seek(this.offset_write-this.offset_read);

                while ((len = this.out.read(text)) > 0) 
                {
                    this.hmac.update(text);
                }

                // write last block of HMAC
                text=this.hmac.doFinal();
                this.out.write(text);
            }

                        // Close streams
            this.in.close();
            this.out.close();

                        // Code to notify the end of the thread
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Hola!");
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

With this code if I execute only 1 thread, the encryption/decryption goes perfect, but with 2+ threads there is a problem with bytes in the zone between threads jobs, the data gets corrupted there and the checksum also fails.

I'm trying to do this with threads because it gets near 2x faster than with one thread, I think it should be because of processing and not by the accessing of the file.

As a irrelevant data, it compress 250Mb of data in 43 seconds on a MB Air. ¿It's a good time?

Comment: Don't bother. Multiple threads will just make things *much* slower. The multiple reads and writes will slow down I/O because file operations are fastest when sequential. And having to re-assemble the data before the HMAC operation will waste time. (What chaining mode are you using?)

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons for that. If you care about performance, you should try to figure out what they are. (Was the data already in cache? Did you forget to feed the data to the HMAC function sequentially? Are you sure you actually processed *all* the data?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, I feed the data sequentially when the last chunk of data gets processed. It actually don't check if all the threads are finished, but with debug information i can assure that all of them gets ended in my tests.

Comment: A typical modern CPU can AES encrypt about 80MB/s and HMAC about 100MB/s. You have a lot of I/O too though.

Comment: Yes, I've read that the major performance problem is the JVM, that dont take care of some special functions of modern CPUs in this type of ops

Comment: Yeah, you're starting with one hand tied behind your back.

Answer (score 5):

AESCrypt is [not thread safe](http://read.pudn.com/downloads144/sourcecode/crypt/628305/aescrypt-java/src/es/vocali/util/AESCrypt.java__.htm). You cannot use multiple threads with it.

Generally speaking, encryption code is rarely thread safe, as it requires complex mathematics to generate secure output. AES by itself is relatively fast, if you need better speed from it, consider vertical scaling or hardware accelerators as a first step. Later, you can add more servers to encrypt *different* files concurrently (horizontal scaling).

Comment: I know it, but I have different instances of cipher object and do the HMAC sequentially when all the data is encrypted, so I don't know what could be the problem. Is important the data processed before of a chunk for AES? Because the problem is in approx 16/32 bytes just in the middel of the file when it get's decrypted. The rest of the files are equal in binary terms

Comment: Do the different objects operate on same file concurrently?

Comment: yes, buy i use 2 different RandomFileAccess objects in "rw" mode that don't block the operation of other threads because they have different offsets

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to multithread an operation that is intrinsically **sequential**.

`Stream cipher` cannot be made parallel because each block depends on the completion of the previous block. So you **can** encrypt multiple files in parallel independently with slight performance increase, especially if the files are in memory rather than on disk, but you **cannot** encrypt a single file using multiple cores.

As I can see, you use an `update` method. I'm not an expert in Java crypography but even the name of the method tells me that the encryption algorithm holds a **state**: "multithreading" and "state" are not friends, you have to deal with state management across threads.

Race condition explains why you get blocks damaged.

Comment: [ESSIV and XEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTS_mode#Encrypted_salt-sector_initialization_vector_.28ESSIV.29) solve that problem. There are fully-parallelizable chaining modes with built in message integrity so HMAC is not even needed.

Comment: And if i generate different encrypted files of chunks of the original (for 2 threads, 2 encrypted files, each one of a middle of the original file), and the gets them decrypted and merged again in the decryption? It should work, nope?

Comment: @odarriba: You can design it either way. You can make it fail by using a per-file IV.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz And could them be used in Cipher?

Comment: I don't know of any Java implementations of XEX or ESSIV, but they're not hard to implement.

Comment: there are chaining modes which don't require knowledge of previous data blocks (CNT, XEX, ESSIV...)

Answer (score 1):

It makes absolutely no sense to use more than 1 thread for the HMAC because 1) it has to be computed sequentially and 2) I/O access R/W is much slower than actual HMAC computation

For AES it can be a good idea to use multiple threads when using CNT mode or other chaining modes which don't require knowledge of previous data blocks.

what about moving the question to crypto-stackexchange?